# Página - Debate civil respeitoso em falta

Tags: bug, status-pronto, comportamento, comunidade, sinalização

Eu não sei se vocês já repararam (com certeza já devem ter reparado), quando sinalizamos uma pergunta para atenção de moderação, existem várias opções de escolha para sugestão do porquê dessa pergunta estar a ser sinalizada.

Entre elas existe a opção:

> - rude ou abusivo
>     O conteúdo não contribui para um [**debate civil e respeitoso**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).

No entanto o link para a página `debate civil e respeitoso` apresentado nesta opção está quebrado, ou seja esta página não existe.

Eu penso que o conteúdo a ser apresentado nesta página seria o mesmo conteúdo da página:
[**Be nice**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) - como existe no Stack Overflow em Inglês.

Isto é devido à falta de tradução para esta página ou foi apenas uma página que faltou criar?

Comment: Parece que está faltando essa seção na nossa central de ajuda mesmo. [Central de ajuda do SO - Our model](http://stackoverflow.com/help/stackexchange); [Central de ajuda do SOPT - Nosso modelo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/stackexchange)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

São as duas coisas. A página não foi criada por não ter tradução. Falha minha.
Vou providenciar.

## Update

Nosso guia "[Seja respeitoso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)" está no ar, plenamente traduzido. Qualquer problema ou sugestões na tradução, só avisar no Meta.

Comment: "Seja receptivo e paciente, principalmente com quem sabe menos que você." +1k